# EF Core ошибка с запросом с группировкой и Count()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Нужно получить последний елемент с групп, группируя по нескольким полям. Используя эту кверю:

```
using(var context = new EFCoreDemoContext())
{
    IQueryable<Book> query = context.Books.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
        .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date ).FirstOrDefault());
     //it's ok
    var data = query.ToArray()
    //it's System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value. exception here
    var count = query.Count();
}
```

Получаю ошибку "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Nullable object must have a value.'". Использую Net 6 + "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6".

Что странно, кверя работает ок с `query.ToArray()`

Есть идеи?

Минимальный пример:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Console.WriteLine("Start");

using(var context = new EFCoreDemoContext())
{
    IQueryable<Book> query = context.Books.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month })
        .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date ).FirstOrDefault());

    var count = query.Count();
}
Console.WriteLine("End");

public class EFCoreDemoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=EFCoreDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
}
```

Comment: Уточните, что именно вам нужно? Если количество групп, то не нужно получать последний элемент. Просто уберите это из запроса. / А если нужно получить из БД последние элементы в группах, то потом у массива возьмите длину `Length`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оба варианта не подходят. 1. Нужно получать данные тоже. 2. Нужен пейджинг, так что инмемори Length не подходит

Comment: А где тут пейджинг? Не вижу `Skip/Take`. / `Count()` нужен, как я понимаю, для получения общего количества страниц, чтобы показать его в UI? Для этого вызовите запрос без `Select`, только с `GroupBy`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну... Это две разные квери для одного запроса. в принципе, как воркараунд можно попробовать. Тут вопрос скорее почему, на первый взгляд валидная квери, ошибку бросает

Comment: Ваша проблема в таймминге. Первый заапрос еще не вернул результат, а в игру вступает уже следующая операция. Например, в Select  выполеяется еще OderBY , а  программа пытается выполнить FirstOrDefault.  Во - первых Вам никто не запрешал записывать  вместо Select вот так 
.FirstOrDefault(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date ))
Вл-вторых иногда действительно на больших запросах сделать сначала ToList(), а потом брать первый элемент или делать сортировку

Comment: @WinnerIT хм. Разве оно не должно одну кверю одним запросом делать (ну может кроме там внутренних оптимизаций с джонами)?  ".FirstOrDefault(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date ))" - Сannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Book>' to 'bool'. Да и оно не доходит до момента запроса, все валится еще при попытке генерации квери

Comment: _Это две разные квери для одного запроса_ - у вас **два разных** запроса. Поэтому две квири. Вот, например, в официальном [туториале](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-paging-to-students-index) можно глянуть: там два запроса с Count и ToList.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov "кверяЭ имел ввиду IQuerable c дополнениями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поведение запроса с [GroupBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby) соответствует спецификации.
Когда к первоначальному запросу применяется вызов `Count()` провайдер не понимает, что ему делать с теми данными, которые получаются в `Select`. Ведь они не используются в `Count`.

Я не совсем понимаю проблему.
Нужно получить общее количество сгрупированных данных - хорошо, получаем его первым запросом.
Потом нужно получить сами данные с определённой страницы - хорошо, получаем их вторым запросом. Материализуем в массив.

```
var query = context.Books.GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month });

IQueryable<Book> pagedQuery = query
    //.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Year)
    .Skip(10).Take(10)
    .Select(y => y.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault());

var count = query.Count();
var array = pagedQuery.ToArray();
```

---

Можно включить логирование запросов, добавив в метод `OnConfiguring` следующую строку:

```
optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
```

Это позволит легко экспериментировать и отлаживать запросы.
В частности, выдаётся подсказка, что при использовании методов `Take/Skip` крайне желательно использовать `OrderBy`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, в принципе работает, и кверя типа одна. Не совсем понял о "спецификации", там где-то обьясняется почему запрос как в вопросе должен выбрасывать ошибку?

Comment: @Ssss - дополнил